# Google Sites Content Security Policy

Tags: iframe, content-security-policy, google-sites

I'm trying to embed a URL from a server we control onto a Google Site using a Full Page Embed, but I keep getting the error:

**"Can't embed due to provider site permissions. URL will display as a text link."**

I figured it was simply a matter of fixing the Content-Security-Policy in Apache, but clearly either I'm doing something wrong with that header or there's something else missing.

I tried the following:

> Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.google.com https://google.com;

> Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' *;

> Content-Security-Policy: default-src *  data: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-dynamic'; script-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src * data: blob: ; style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One fairly insecure way to do this is actually to just disable all of the default security headings:

Header unset X-Frame-Options
Header unset Content-Security-Policy

Answer (score 0):

Set the Content-Security-Policy to:

```
frame-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self' sites.google.com www.gstatic.com *.googleusercontent.com; object-src 'none';
```

And the X-Frame-Options to:

```
ALLOW-FROM https://sites.google.com/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).